# Creating a user authentication system for iOS (previously with Parse hopefully AWS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

Since Parse is going away, I had initially used their _User and PFUser implementation to create a user authentication process.

I have since begun switching to Amazon's AWS Mobilie Hub. I did notice in the Amazon Cognito system that they allow Google, Facebook, Amazon credential providers, which I don't want to use yet.

I go see the choice for a custom provider. Do I have to create my own backend auth system with a client and server side code for this to work?

Is there a simple way (but secure) login process for iOS like Parse had?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated (been reading a lot online).

Comment: This is quite broad but hope the answer helps - Questions should be more focused on the exact problem you're having. Not "How do I do this" - more of "Why doesn't this code work"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I use AWS Custom Authentication all the time.

[Check this out](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/) and another [answer I posted for custom authentication here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393152/verifying-user-is-authenticated-using-aws-ios-sdk/41427360#41427360)

So the steps are:

1. Set up Cognito to authenticate UNanthenticated users

   - You have to do this otherwise they won't be able to access anything *before* logging in.
     [image: unauthenticated user]

**AND your authentic user Developer Name** <- important part

[image: developer name]

2. Set up DynamoDB (or whatever) to store your Username-Password information
3. Go to IAM and make an `AUTHENTICATED` role and an `UNAUTHENTICATED` role.
4. You give the `UNAUTHENTICATED` role, assign:

   AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities
   AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess (if you want a Login & Register system)
   AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess (if you only want login)

[image: IAM roles]

5. Also go in and do:

`Edit Trust Relationship`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<YOUR_COG_ARN>"
            },
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

6. Now make your `AUTHENTICATED` role, and assign:

   AmazonCognitoPowerUser
   AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
   AmazonSNSFullAccess - for example, and whatever else you'd like
7. Also go in and do:

`Edit Trust Relationship`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<YOUR_COG_ARN>"
            },
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

> PLEASE NOTICE THE ONE CHANGE MADE - "authenticated" and "unauthenticated"

8. Now this should be mobile hubs responsibility, but since they came out with that, everyone thinks they're relieved of responsibility! Not the case! You need to know what `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`
9. Now that you have everything set up, start your xcode project form Mobile Hub
10. Fill in all the data (if its not there, which it should be because Mobile-Hub is nice to us) for your `AUTHENTICATED ARN` and your `UNATHENTICATED ARN`
11. Set up your login page
12. When the user goes to login, (encrypt their password) and send that and the username to DynamoDB.

12B. I really like using Lambda PARTICULARLY for mobile because you can really do a lot more AND you are less prone to errors AND you have more control, etc.

So with that said, go back to to step 4 & 6 IF you want to use Lambda and add and `Inline Policy` to the `Roles`. IAM -> Roles -> Your Role -> `Create Role Policy`
And pop in:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }]
}
```

Now that you have the base set up, go back to Xcode.

13. IF you are using Lambda, send in your username and password, let lambda pull the row from DynamoDB AND do the check on `does the user exist, if so do the passwords match`

Should look something like this in Lambda:

```
const
    AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB()

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var params = {
        TableName : '<users>',
        KeyConditionExpression : 'userType = :v_type AND username = :v_user',
        FilterExpression : 'password = :v_pass',
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
            ':v_type' : { S : '<superdooper>' },
            ':v_user' : { S : event.username },
            ':v_pass' : { S : event.password }
        }
        //ProjectionExpression: 'email, joinDate, phone' (OPTIONAL)
    }
    ddb.query (params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail (JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            if (data.Count !== 0)
                context.succeed (data.Items);
            else
                context.succeed ('Wrong Info');
        }
    });
};
```

Once you get your data.Items back in Xcode, call this Lambda function, send in your variables, and when they say "good", call:

```
credentialsProvider.setLogins({developerAuthenticationProvider.getProviderName(), developerUserIdentifier});
```

Followed by `credentialsProvider.refresh();`

That part above should be in your Xcode project from MobileHub.

Now, this is were things get weird. There are a ton o` ways to do this. [TVM](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490), Cognito Assume Auth, server side, etc.

I always reassume authentication from `Unauthenticated` to `Authenticated`, but you have to do a lot of back end stuff if you want to get real analytics from both web side and mobile side if you're making this for both. But once you have your authenticated user, you now have a well authenticated user, ready to access whatever you listed in Step 6 as authenticated!

Hope this helps.

**Update --- This is a dirty, unsafe, but fast way to do this. NOT FOR PRODUCTION.**

In cognito, don't even make an `Authenticated user role`. Give your `Unauthenticated user role` all the permissions to do everything (`DynamoDBFullAccess`, `S3FullAccess`, `EC2FullAccess`, etc)

Then handle your authentication in the phone - Check the username and password against DynamoDB and then if it returns the information, set a variable to `TRUE`. This is not safe because the user now has access to all your stuff but it would look like this:

```
BOOL loggedIn = FALSE;
if (loggedIn) {
    [self loadView];
} else {
    [self loadLoginView];
}

- (void) loadLoginView {
    DynamoDBCall (username, password) withCompletion () {
        if (allGood) {
            _loggedIn = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome this is more of what I am looking for. So this is all on AWS and my Xcode iOS project correct?

Comment: What do you mean by *this*. Just trying to get a better understanding

Comment: Oh you mean "This" and all these steps? Correct, there is no need for another party like Parse or anything like that. **Although**, it is recommended that you give the option for Google, Facebook, and Amazon login options

Comment: Cool that sounds good. Thanks.

Comment: You got it! Hope it works out

Comment: One side note, how do you get a forgot password reset link generated/sent?

Comment: Hmm. Might need to be another question. Please feel free to email or message me. That would be quite a bit out of the scope of this question and the answer would not fit in a comment box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102307/discussion-between-iskore-and-chris).

Comment: now i get this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35145550/665557 how do i dm you?

Comment: @iSkore, I tried to do this process but I am stuck since tow days in the lambda part 12B. When I copy/past the Create Role Policy, I have the following error : This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies. I looked in lambda, Cognito and IAM, but I don't really understand what to do. Maybe it is linked with "IAM users" as I have none. – Omnia69 2 days ago

Comment: Yes, you need IAM Users