# Amazon Cognito Identity Pool can not be found

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm making an app that uploads photos to an S3 bucket using the AWS SDK with Amazon Cognito. When I run the function that does this I get an error in the console that says the `Identity Pool [the id of my identity pool] can't be found`. I've found a few solutions to this issue around the internet. However, none of them seem to work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey just wanted to check back and see if you got this problem solved

Comment: I did, but this forum did not solve it @iSkore

Comment: Gotcha, can you post your solution? You can answer your own questions too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your ARN configuration for your Auth and Unauth are the full ARN

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the correct identity pool id, you may not be connecting to the same region that the pool was created in.  The region is the first portion of the identity pool id.  Incorrect access policies will not cause this error.  I caution against granting blanket access to your resources, if end users will only be reading and writing from s3, only provide that access, don't give them full access.

Answer (score 1):

Each time I get this issue it is because the IAM role does not have permissions to view the pool OR the pool does not have `Unauthenticated Identities`

Add `AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities` OR `AmazonCognitoPowerUser` to your IAM role

You will need some level of S3 access attached to your policy in the future to access S3.

Also, please add more information to your question. Code used, information about the pool set up, etc. Also, review my answer for [Setting up Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136637/creating-a-user-authentication-system-for-ios-previously-with-parse-hopefully-a/35140150#35140150)

**Edit:**

Per [@justderb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178781/justderb)’s comment - removed reference to `AmazonS3FullAccess` and updated appropriately.

Comment: -1. Careful when giving "Admin" policies to Roles that can be assumed via customers! You should always scope down your policies to be as minimal as possible. Giving `AmazonS3FullAccess` to a Cognito Authenticated Role means a customer can delete anything (even your bucket) from your account!