# Installing CocoaPods and AWS Mobile iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, cocoapods, aws-mobilehub

I followed these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/install-ios-sdk.html

But I still get all these missing dependencies: http://screencast.com/t/o2oaYFctzg

How do I fix this?

Comment: which file you are opening after pod setup? are you working on .xcworkspace?

Comment: yes i am using that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had issues with this for a while too. A bit confusing if it is your first dependency manager.

So open up terminal and follow these steps:

1. `gem --help` to check if you have RubyGems. If not go [HERE](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods` IT TAKES A WHILE, be patient, it will go
3. Now, once that's done, `cd` into your directory where your `.xcodeproj` is
4. Create your [Podfile](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html): `nano Podfile` NO extension
5. Include your packages `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'` for instance

And all your AWS packages:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'AWSCore'
pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
pod 'AWSEC2'
pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
pod 'AWSKinesis'
pod 'AWSLambda'
pod 'AWSMachineLearning'
pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSSES'
pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
pod 'AWSSNS'
pod 'AWSSQS'
pod 'AWSCognito'
```

6. Exit and save from nano `CTRL+X`
7. `pod install`
8. Open your `.xcworkspace`

Comment: strangely if i do a clean project still get the red files but build succeeds so I'll start from there

Comment: Ya that is common with Cocoapods if you have them linked. *Basically* a workspace encompasses *two* xcode projects. One for your project development, and one for all the frameworks your pods install. You should be able to still build this. Dont forget you reference it like: `#import "AWSCore.h"` and **not** `#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>`

Comment: No problem, I suppose a better solution to your comment would be, hit `CMD + SHIFT + K` to clean up the project, if those files get 'found' (which they won't) erase those red files because they're useless. Make sure the `pods` project is in there and it should be good to go. Hit up my email and I can send a read to go project folder to you.